# How to initialize a dynamic c style array

Tags: arrays, cocoa, xcode

I'm working in objective-c and I'm allocating a dynamic array of floats, but the size depends on the size of another array. So my allocations goes something like this:

```
float myFloats[[myArray count]];
```

All is working fine except when I do an analyze build in xcode. When using an element of the array a get a message like "The right operand is garbage value"

I've tried initializing going through all the elements and setting them to zero, but the analyze compiler does not take it into account.

Any one knows how to do it properly?

```
    NSRect actualSuperFrame = [self frame];

 //Here I initialize the float array.
float clicksFromMiddle[[self.plannerViewArray count]];

NSRect actualPlannerFrame[[self.plannerViewArray count]];
PlannerView *plannerView;
for(int i = 0; i < [self.plannerViewArray count];i++){
    plannerView = [self.plannerViewArray objectAtIndex:i];
    actualPlannerFrame[i] = [plannerView frame];


    //Below is where the values are set.
    if (plannerView.isLeftPage) {
        clicksFromMiddle[i] =  (actualSuperFrame.origin.x + (actualSuperFrame.size.width/2.0))-NSMaxX(actualPlannerFrame[i]);            
    }
    else{
        clicksFromMiddle[i] =  (actualPlannerFrame[i].origin.x-(actualSuperFrame.origin.x + (actualSuperFrame.size.width/2.0)));            

    }

}





[super setFrame:frameRect];
NSRect modifiedPlannerFrame[[self.plannerViewArray count]];
for(int i = 0; i < [self.plannerViewArray count];i++){
    plannerView = [self.plannerViewArray objectAtIndex:i];
    modifiedPlannerFrame[i] = [plannerView frame];

    if(plannerView.isLeftPage){
        //This next line is where I get the message, right operand of "-" is garbage value
        float newMaxX = (frameRect.origin.x +(frameRect.size.width/2.0))-clicksFromMiddle[i];
        float newWidth = newMaxX-modifiedPlannerFrame[i].origin.x;


        [plannerView setFrame:NSMakeRect(modifiedPlannerFrame[i].origin.x, modifiedPlannerFrame[i].origin.y,newWidth , modifiedPlannerFrame[i].size.height)];        
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce this analyzer warning using the following code, with or without the `bzero()`. I intentionally read of the end of the array, just to demonstrate what is and is not 0-initialized. Can you provide some additional code that demonstrates the problem?

```
NSArray *myArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"foo", @"bar", nil];
float myFloats[[myArray count]];
//bzero(myFloats, sizeof(myFloats));
myFloats[0] = 1.0;

printf("%f\n", myFloats[0]);   // 1.0
printf("%f\n", myFloats[1]);   // 0.0
printf("%f\n", myFloats[2]);   // random number
```

Answer (score 0):

Click on the analyzer flag in your source code editor. It'll show you the complete set of steps it followed to arrive at the conclusion that it should flag. You probably forgot to initialize something in some case.

We could probably tell you more ourselves if we could see your code. You may want to edit your question to include the implementation of the relevant method.